Running my Pixi.js project in a react Native screen using expo go
I can't get my game to load within my app screen.  As far as I can see its been bundled correctly and works in a browser using LiveServer but when I try to get it to load on the native app screen I just get a blank screen.  I can't see any errors its just not working.
import { View, Button } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
export default function GameScreen ({ route, navigation }) {
  const GameHTML = require('../../dist/index.html');
  //const GameBundle = require('../dist/bundle.js');
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         <Button
            title="Back" 
            onPress={() => 
                navigation.navigate("Play") 
            }/>
          <WebView 

            source={ GameHTML }
            style={{flex: 1}}
            originWhitelist={['*']}//this line should avoid cors errors
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            
          />
            
          
       </View>
      );
    }
  

I expected that when I navigated to this screen the game would start exactly as it does in the browser but I only get a blank screen.
Edit:  After much messing around I felt like I had gotten close to the answer, I was still getting a black screen however an error message appeared saying Error: 'bundle.js' cannot be loaded as its extension is not registered in 'assetExts'.  I navigated to the metro-config defaults and found the default extension before I realised bundle.js is not an asset it is a source file.  I have absolutely no idea why this error is occurring but if I was coding genius like some of you out there it might be a good clue.
As it is I've spent around 20-25 hours trying to get this damn game to launch in a Webview to no avail.

This question is similar to: (React Native) Load local HTML file into WebView. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is but the answer to that question didn't help
